# Compilation of Python extension on windows fails with missing source filename error D8003

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build qpython (the kdb python interface) for python 3.6.3 (Anaconda) running on windows 7.

After downloading and unpacking qPython-qPython-1.2.2.zip

Executing "python setup.py build_ext --inplace"

gives...

```
running build_ext
building 'qpython.fastutils' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\wilsoroh\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\inclu
de -IC:\Users\wilsoroh\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\wilsoroh\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\
Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\u
m" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Sy
base\OCS-15_0\include\" /Tcqpython/fastutils.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\qpython/fastutils.obj
cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Which looks like setup is simply not setting the paths up correctly for the compiler.

A look in the qpython directory below shows fastutils.c sitting there waiting to be compiled.

This kind of thing seems to be a regular problem when trying to build python extensions on windows.

Any help / suggestions greatly appreciated.